# How to combine two NSDictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to merge 2 `NSDictionary` objects into 1 `NSMutableDictionary`. `NSDictionary`s are created by reading 2 distinct `plist` files.

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *configuration;
    ...
    -(NSMutableDictionary*) configuration{
    if (!_configuration) {
      NSDictionary *core_config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"installation" ofType:@"plist"]];
      NSDictionary *app_config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/path/to"] pathForResource:@"something/data" ofType:@"plist"]];
      [_configuration addEntriesFromDictionary: core_config];
      [_configuration addEntriesFromDictionary: app_config];
      NSLog(@"merged: %lu, core: %lu, app: %lu", (unsigned long)[_configuration count],  (unsigned long)[core_config count],  (unsigned long)[app_config count]);
      // merged: 0, core: 4, app: 5
    }
    return _configuration;
    }
```

The `_configuration` is empty, despite calling `addEntriesFromDictionary` twice.

Comment: What's your question? What issue are you having?

Comment: but you never create your merged _confguration object? if it is nil --- first create an NSMutableDictionary in _configuration, then [_configuration addEntriesFromDictionary:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you init your NSMutableDictionary before adding entries to it?

```
NSMutableDictionary *configuration = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yeah! Just realised it wasn't initialised. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*) configuration{
    if (!_configuration) {
        NSDictionary *core_config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"installation" ofType:@"plist"]];
        NSDictionary *app_config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Volumes/RolloutSDKInstaller"] pathForResource:@".rollout/app" ofType:@"plist"]];
        _configuration = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: core_config];
        [_configuration addEntriesFromDictionary: app_config];
        NSLog(@"merged: %lu, core: %lu, app: %lu", (unsigned long)[_configuration count],  (unsigned long)[core_config count],  (unsigned long)[app_config count]);
        //merged: 9, core: 4, app: 5
    }

    return _configuration;
}
```